# Pandas fill dataframe from another dataframe where the [non-] index doesnt always overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes where I want to pull out a single column from each and merge them into another dataframe with a timestamp column that is not indexed.

So e.g. all the dataframes look like:

```
[Index] [time]                [col1]   [col2] [etc]
0       2020-04-21T18:00:00Z    1        2     ...
```

All of the dataframes have a 'time' column and a 'col1' column. Because the 'time' column does not necessarily overlap, I made a new dataframe with a join of all the dataframes (that I added to a dictionary)

```
di = ... #dictionary of all the dataframes of interest

for key in di:
    temptimeslist = di[key]['time'].tolist()
    fulltimeslist.extend(x for x in temptimeslist if x not in fulltimeslist)

datadf['time'] = fulltimeslist #make a new df and add this as a column
```

(i'm sure there's an easier way to do the above, any suggestions are welcome). **Note that for a number of reasons, translatting the ISO datetime format into a datetime and setting that as an index is not ideal**.

The dumb way to do what I want is obvious enough:

```
for key in di:
    datadf[key] = float("NaN")
    tempdf = di[key]  #could skip this probably
    for i in range(len(datadf)):
        if tempdf.time[tempdf.time==datadf.time[i]].index.tolist():
             if len(tempdf.time[tempdf.time==datadf.time[i]].index.tolist())==1: #make sure value only shows up once, could reasonably skip this and put protection in elsewhere
                    datadf.loc[i,key] = float(tempdf[colofinterest][tempdf.time[tempdf.time==datadf.time[i]].index.tolist()])
                    #i guess i could do the above backwards so i loop over only the shorter dataframe to save some time.
```

but this seems needlessly long for python...I originally tried the pandas merge and join methods but got various keyerrors when trying them...same goes for 'in' statements inside the if statements.

e.g, I've tried thins like

```
datadf.join(Nodes_dict[key],datadf['time']==Nodes_dict[key]['time'],how="left").select()
```

but this fails.

I guess the question boils down to the following steps:

1) given 2 dataframes with a column of strings (times in iso format), find the indexes in the larger one for where they match the shorter one (or vice versa)
2) given that list of indexes, populate a separate column in the larger df using values from the smaller df but only in the correct spots and nan otherwise

Comment: Did you tried to convert your time type columns into a string then merging them ?

Comment: The times are already in string because of the ISO format that is slightly different from the datetime.datetime.isoformat.  Doing something like 
df1.merge(df2['col1'], on='time')
gives a "KeyError:'time'"

Comment: Ok so I figured out the keyerror and made something work with the following:

df1 = df1[['time']].merge(df2[['time','col1']],on='time',how='left')
and then renaming the col1 in df1 to the key.  I guess it's better?

Comment: For anyone who sees this the correct syntax is: datadf = datadf[:].merge(tempdf[['time','col1']],on='time',how='left')